# Is there any relationship between CSS ID selector and fragment identifier?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to understand the difference between ID and Class selectors by making different color boxes.

HTML

```css
.box-a{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

#box-b{
  background-color: #ffe666;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-a" id="box-b"></div>
<div class="box-a"></div>
```

Most of the articles on this subject have been read by me. But I remained intrigued. I just so happened to learn about fragment IDs, how the browser only retains them, and how the (#) hash character identifies a document part.

Is this the main justification for ID selectors' higher specificity than class selectors, then?

Comment: specificity weight is quite self-explaining: tag < class < id. What is more specific to address someone? The guy from the class xy or the guy with the name z? The thing is a class address all elements with that class while an ID is unique and as such you only return one very specific element instead of a group. `#` is the identifier in CSS (and `querySelector` for an ID just as a `.` is the identifier for a class. It is just a definition. It could have been defined with any other character as well.

Comment: Could you explain what 'how the browser only retains them' means? I am not understanding part of your question.

Comment: @AHaworth I read here: https://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/

Comment: Do you mean the bit in that source which says "the fragment identifier is only used by the browser – it doesn’t affect which resource is returned from the server."?

Comment: The relationship between CSS id selectors and fragment identifiers is that they both make use of the HTML id attribute.